# onMouseHover for user drawn controls

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a large user drawn control that fills most of the screen area in an application.

I would like to simulate some "onMouseHover" behaviour, I cant really use the userControl event as the mouse is almost always on that control so it fires all of the time.

How can I detect the mouse "hovering" over part of my user drawn control?

(If it helps an image of the app can be found at : http://www.benbun.co.uk/st3/ayv the control is the large "year calendar")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle MouseMove events instead of MouseHover. Then you could calculate based on the X,Y location of the mouse whether or not the cursor is in the part of your control you are interested in creating "hover" behavior for.